# Python json key error

Tags: python, json

So I'm using the following simple snippet code to import a JSON object and then pull out specific fields into a list. Here it is:

```
#Set Observations URL request for all observations within the Osa Pennisula, Costa Rica
query = urllib2.urlopen("http://api.inaturalist.org/v1/observations?nelat=8.60586&nelng=-83.44410&swlat=8.43066&swlng=-83.74073&per_page=1000&order=desc&order_by=created_at")
obSet = json.load(query)

#Find all common names for observations


for item in obSet['results']:
   print item['taxon']['preferred_common_name']
```

The URL is a call to the iNaturalist `node.js` service. When I make the call I get the following result:

```
Red Brocket
Gumbo Limbo
Northern Tamandua
Colubrids
Bats
Skippers
True Toads
Crested Owl
Tropical Screech-Owl
White-nosed Coati
Central American Squirrel Monkey
Thread-legged Bugs
Roadside Hawk
Barn Owl
Red Land Crab
Crested Caracar

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-255-6e709d365b1b> in <module>()
     3 
     4 for item in obSet['results']:
     ----> 5     print item['taxon']['preferred_common_name']
     6 
     7 

KeyError: 'preferred_common_name'
```

So it's odd - I know that the response has 304 results, but the code seems to print a few out and then blow up. Why is this?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because not every item in `obSet['results']` has key `item['taxon']['preferred_common_name']`.

You can counteract that by catching these `KeyError`s and printing the offensive keys. It also seems like some items have `None` as value for `'taxon'` key, so you may want to catch these as well:

```
for item in obSet['results']:
     try:
          print item['taxon']['preferred_common_name']
     except (KeyError, TypeError):
          print item
```

Comment: ok - I have added your edits to the question above- as this solved them problem!

Comment: @AnthonyW See my updated answer, it solves both of your issues.